# Can there be different After-Tax contribution limits for HCE and NHCE in a Mega Backdoor Roth 401k?

Tags: united-states, 401k, roth-401k, hce

Is it possible in a 401k plan with ***Mega Backdoor Roth*** to have different ***After-Tax*** *contribution amount* limits for each employee depending on whether they're part of the ***HCE*** or ***NHCE*** group?

For example, if an employee is in the NHCE group, then the After-Tax limit is 50% or even 90%.  Else, if the employee is HCE, then the limit is just 10%.  Is that even allowed in a 401k?  Do common 401k trustees like Fidelity support such logic?

This may especially matter for things like Mega Backdoor Roth, where the overall limit of 58k/year/employer (as of 2021) is much higher than the total Elective Deferral limit for Pre-Tax/Roth of just 19.5k/year (as of 2021).

In turn, a single unified 30% limit for both HCEs and NHCEs may result in ***Actual Contribution Percentage (ACP)*** test for After-Tax contributions failing, because there may be more HCEs who'd participate at full 30% than there may be NHCEs.

On the other extreme, if the limit is the same 10% for everyone, then some eager NHCEs would actually be the ones most negatively impacted for no good reason as their total contribution limit would be much lower in absolute terms (10% of 50k is just 5k, whereas 10% of 150k is 15k -- compare to the 19.5k limit that's the same for everyone), and these NHCEs who may be capable of contributing 50% or more to bring the ACP averages for the whole NHCE group significantly upwards would be denied an opportunity to do so, thus keeping everyone down at the lower limit forever.

Comment: Highly compensated and non-highly compensated isn’t the concern of the participant it’s a designation in the non discrimination rules. Generally, unless you’re in one of the statutory definitions like 5% owner or director of the company, you won’t even necessarily know if you’re a highly compensated employee. Most 401(k) plans don’t even allow Roth contributions and/or “in service distributions” so bockdoor transactions are moot unless you’re leaving the company. Separately it should go without saying that the only people contributing anywhere near the upper limits will be the high earners.

Comment: @quid Not every high earner is an HCE; especially not as a newhire, even at the senior level.  Because of the way the HCE/NHCE designation lags behind the plan years, you're actually always an NHCE when you join any given company you've never worked for before, even if your first year's TC is way above the 130k threshold -- you'll be an NHCE for either one or two plan years (two if your partial-year compensation didn't cross the 130k barrier).  If you've already exhausted the 19.5k limit at the prior employer, after-tax is effectively the only thing you can participate in for the first year.

Comment: I know not every high earner is an HCE, that’s my point, and you’d have know way of knowing you’re an HCE because one of the rules could be that you need to be a top 20% of earners at the company.  Separately, you need to be a “high earner” to be in a place to part with the better part of $20k for retirement.  It should be fairly obvious to everyone that someone earning 80k probably isn’t parting with a quarter of their income for retirement.  And none of this matters but for non-discrimination testing which participants have no part of.  I don’t know what you’re trying to accomplish.

Comment: It’s like you read something about non discrimination test rules and think they apply to the individual participants but they don’t, the plan is tested in aggregate (by the plan sponsor in the background and the results aren’t published to the participants) and if it fails the sponsor has to either make a “qualified non elective contribution” to the non HCEs (all of them) or pull out contributions from HCEs which might just be c suite or contributions over some threshold.

Comment: Though sometimes companies will or won’t allow certain things for folks whose salary is over $130k, generally to avoid a nondiscrim failure.  As an example in 2020 many companies suspended employer match contributions for people with salaries over $130k.  But the company will typically advertise this to the participants as explicitly “salary over $130k” or whatever.

Comment: @quid, I understand all that; I'm trying to figure out this information so that I can lobby the 401k committee to make the requisite changes to our plan

Comment: I’m happy to delete all my comments to not distract but I think you need to edit this question to focus in on the specific limit you’re running in to and what you would like to convince your company/plan sponsor to change in order to affect the goal you’re trying to achieve.  Plans can certainly discriminate *against* HCEs.  I’d say the biggest problem you’ll run in to with your 401k committee is you don’t know what the nondiscrim pain point is because you don’t know which part of the tests the plan is close to failing if any and this will be unique to your plan.

Comment: @quid The limit I'm running into is that my After-Tax elections are too small to my liking.  The whole question is in the first paragraph.  I think most people don't realise that even if someone's making TC of 1M/year at a Silicon Valley corp and are in the top-20%, they're still NHCE in the first year on the job, since their employer-sourced income was 0 the prior plan year, hence I think they should have a higher limit than just 10% as an HNCE in order to be able to pad the NHCE numbers (esp. since often most of the TC is often in stock that's not part of these contribution settings).

Comment: What is 10%, is that your plan’s limit?  If the first paragraph is the whole question delete the rest of the question because it’s not clear any of it attaches to your plan and isn’t just speculation and random examples.  And if the first paragraph is your whole question, yes plans are allowed to discriminate against HCEs, so yes imposing a more restrictive limit on HCEs than non-HCEs would generally be allowed.  Also there’s a comp maximum for nondiscrim testing (and matching rules) which I think is $290k for 2021 so whether you make 1mm or 290k it’s the same in the testing.